# On rowDeleting exit function on error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to run a query that checks if the foreign key has a relationship in another table associated with the delete query.

In my gridview_RowDeleting function I check to see if their is a foreign key relationship and if there is, I want to send a JavaScript alert back to the user that they cannot delete this item.

The alert gets fired, but keeps on running and then displays the error page:

---

**Server Error in '/' Application.**

The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint etc...

I want to exit the function without running the query, is this possible?

This is my code:

```
protected void gridViewEdit_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)

// query to check for PK in other table

if (count > 0) // returns 1 as it should
   {
      Response.Write("<script>alert('Data could not be deleted.   
      Other data in the system is currently referencing this data.'); 
      </script>");
      conn.Close();
      return; // hoping to stop execution of query here...
   }
   else
   {
      Response.Write("<script>alert('No problem here.');</script>");
      conn.Close();
   }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes because you produced an error message but didnt instruct the system to stop!

You need to use the GridViewDeleteEventArgs  (e) to cancel it so you would do

```
if (count>0) 
{ 
   e.cancel;
   //throw error
}
else
{
   //show happy deleted message
}
```

Comment: When I put e.Cancel in there _ i get:    Error CS0201 Compiler Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement and no change in behavior.

Comment: Thanks @BugFinder.  I added `= true` to that and it works!